Is there any mention of Rama worship in Scriptures?
I respect Lord Ram, but is there any mention of Lord Ram worship in any scripture?

Yes, in fact Lord Rama is eternally worshipped in His spiritual realm known as Saketa Dham.




Sri Sita Ram descend to the material world to give a chance to the jivas residing here to worship Them and thus be promoted to Saketa Dham.
Source for further reading.
